# Using sed to extract text from a log file

Tags: unix, sed, grep

I am working on a script that pulls the amount of data backed up from a .log file and emails it to me.  I believe the "sed" function can do this.  The following command shows what I want to see.  In particular, how can I extract the text "Backed-up 6.776 GB"?  If the number changes and becomes TB, the "sed" should still work.  Can "sed" do this?

Command:

```
grep "Backed-up" Daily_Backups-Exchange-1376798400228#0-3018-Exchange_VSS_Writer_2007.log
```

Output:

```
2013-08-18 00:12:44 avtar Info <6083>: Backed-up 6.776 GB in 0.03 minutes: 12,301 GB/hour (0 files/hour)
```

Answer (score 0):

This `sed` line should work:

```
grep "Backed-up" filename.log |sed -e 's/^.* \(Backed-up [0-9\.]* [MGT]B\) in .*$/\1/'
```

It matches MB, GB and TB.

Comment: This is great Olafur!  Thank you.  I also found that using printf in Bash eliminates problems with the newline character \n not being recognized as was happening with echo.

Comment: There's no need to pipe grep to sed.  `grep foo | sed 's/pat/repl/'` is better written as `sed -n '/foo/s/pat/repl/p'`

Answer (score 0):

If your input format is robust with respect to the number of columns:

```
awk '$6 == "Backed-up" { print $6, $7, $8 }' input-file
```

should work just fine.

Comment: William, your awk example certainly makes the code more readable.  How would this work if the word Backed-up was separated by a space as in "Backed up"?  Can we define "Backed up" to be a field even though it has a space in it?

Comment: You could try to define `RS` to "Backed up", but in that case it would probably be easier to do `$6=="Backed" && $7 == "up" { print $6, $7, $8, $9 }`